# Access Replace Function in Update Query - Maintain Number Formatting

Tags: ms-access, replace

I'm running an update query... using the replace function to update a placeholder in a memo field... with a value from a query.

When I run the query, the number that is replaced loses it's formatting. IE... it will update to 1000000, instead of 1,000,000.

Any clue how to do this properly, to maintain the formatting of the number?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] , then improve your question (e.g show query).

Comment: Use Format() function. Edit question to show query if you need more specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating to, say, NewValue, update to:

```
Format(NewValue, "#,##0")
```